# Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, javascript

Привет.
Где посмотреть как устанавливается директория для хранения модулей..

Гружу через require  получаю ошибку :
 **Cannot find module**

Answer (score 1):

[node.js Modules. All together](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together)

если кратко и про файл (без явного указания пути), то

- системные модули
- в текущей директории
- в `./node_modules`, потом `../node_modules`, `../../node_modules` и т.д. до корня.

с директориями аналогично, только в директории ищется index.js

ЗЫ Вы бы привели пример что вы ищите и где...
ЗЗЫ Есть еще поиск в домашней директории юзера, но это не нормальное размещение модулей.
ЗЗЗЫ Если устанавливаете сторонние модули, делайте это через `package.json` (в корне сайта вашего) секция `"dependencies"` и дальше `npm install`, либо в крайнем случае `npm install module`...

Answer (score 1):

есть еще такое - если модуль находится в папке node_modules (в этом же каталоге) то просто пишем require('module_name'); , а если в качестве модуля выступает просто файл в текущей директории то надо написать require('./module_name.js');. Если модуль установлен глобально, то это не означает что он будет доступен во всех проектах.